# Upload Files in the background

Tags: javascript, php

I am recently developing a site with a video upload feature, where I ran into an efficiency-based requirement: I would like my video to keep being uploaded while I browse the site.

Do you have any suggestions or experience that may be helpful?
My site uses PHP as backend, from where I edit the video with FFMPEG and upload it to azure blob.

Comment: I stumbled on the same problem and the easiest solution I found was using a popup (new tab/window) to manage the upload.

Comment: Maybe you can create a hidden iframe and target your upload process to run on the iframe.

Comment: the proper way is to have an spa app. The spa never refresh the page so the upload can continue while the user can navigate through the page.

Comment: I agree that the easiest solution would be a new window for upload, if your site is not fully dynamic (like YT).

Comment: with the new windows solution, what will happen if the video takes long time to upload and the php session is expiring ? or the user can simply forget and logout itself